# How can I view which employees are available across within any of the 3 different databases with 3 tables

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

If I want to check which Employees(represented by letters) are present across 3 different tables in ANY of three different databases. How should my query look like? I dont want to select the whole table and paste it in excel then do a vlookup. Actually I have 13 Databases which I need to join but I only used three sample databases in my question just to explain what my difficulty is. I just need to know what my query should look like. Im thinking of joining my tables across 12 databases using a subquery. Please help.

```
    Database1.ResourceTableUS  Database2.ResourceTableUK     Database3.ResourceTableAUS
col  Employee                   Employee                      Employee

row1  A                         A                             A                   
row2  B                         C                             B
row3  C                         I                             C
row4  E                         J                             K
row5  F                         K                             N
row6  H                         N                             T

Answer: A,B,C,K,N - because these are present at least in two tables (B) or three tables (A) in three databases.
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try:

```
select DISTINCT
    COLUMN_Name
from
    select 
        COLUMN_Name, COUNT(*) over (partition by COLUMN_Name) Num
    FROM(
        select COLUMN_Name from Database1.ResourceTableUS union all
        select COLUMN_Name from Database2.ResourceTableUK union all
        select COLUMN_Name from Database3.ResourceTableAUS
    )x
)xx 
where Num>1
```

Comment: How do I remove the duplicates?  I tried using UNION instead of UNION ALL but UNION gave me zero results.

Comment: Add `DISTINCT` in the outer select, please check the edited answer.

Comment: Use distinct to remove duplicates. `select distinct COLUMN_Name`

Comment: Thank you techdo and DeicLone123

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT A.employeeID FROM
(select * FROM Database1.ResourceTableUS,  Database2.ResourceTableUK,  Database3.ResourceTableAUS
 WHERE Database1.ResourceTableUS.employeeID IN (Database2.ResourceTableUK.employeeID,
 Database3.ResourceTableAUS.employeeID) AND Database2.ResourceTableUK.employeeID IN
 (Database1.ResourceTableUS.employeeID,Database3.ResourceTableAUS.employeeID) AND 
 Database3.ResourceTableAUS.employeeID  IN (Database2.ResourceTableUK.employeeID,Database1.ResourceTableUS.employeeID)) A
```